# cannot find -lgml - GLM in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, glm-math

I am trying to use GLM in my C++ project. I installed the library via synaptics. Then I added glm to the Libraries section of the GCC C++ Linker under:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings.

Unfortunatly, when I try to include glm with # include , the error  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglm appears.

When I uninstall glm, the error changes to  fatal error: glm/glm.hpp: No such file or directory.

Right now, my suspicion is that I need to install something besides libglm-dev or that the package is installed in the wrong place, but the latter sounds unlikely.

Comment: The linker error has nothing to do with the inclusion of the  header files...

Comment: Meaning that I should check/correct what exactly?

Comment: @userXXX The installed libraries, in particular `libglm.so`.

Answer (score 0):

GLM is a header only library (meaning there is no associated library file). You may need to add the location of the installed header files to your project settings in Eclipse (Under Includes in Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings). However, it's likely you just undo the changes to the linker settings to fix your issue (remove glm).